# Agrupar por codigo, devolviendo ultimo id en MYSQL

Tags: mysql, group-by

Tengo una query que toma datos de varias tablas, pero 2 son las mas importantes y están relacionadas por **oc_id**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la query, básicamente agrupa por codigo, y suma cantidad que está en la tabla db1_stock restada con otra tabla (lo hace bien). Sin embargo mi problema es que siempre devuelve los valores del id_stock mas antiguos

```
SELECT s.id_stock, s.oc_id, s.detalle, s.cat_id, s.codigo, s.precio_in, s.id_prov, 
       SUM(s.cantidad) - COALESCE(sv.suma_salidas,0) as cantidad, s.ubicacion, s.id_bodega, 
       p.nom_prov, c.modelo, b.nombre, x.status, c.id_cat
    FROM db1_stock s
    LEFT JOIN 
      (SELECT COALESCE(sum(cant_ser),0) suma_salidas, codigo
       FROM db1_servicios
       GROUP BY codigo) sv USING (codigo)       
    LEFT JOIN 
        db1_proveedores p
        ON (s.id_prov = p.id_prov)
    LEFT JOIN
        db1_cat c
        ON (s.cat_id = c.id_cat)
    LEFT JOIN 
        db1_bodega b
        ON (s.id_bodega = b.id_bodega)
    LEFT JOIN db1_oc x
        ON (s.oc_id = x.oc_id)
    WHERE x.status = '". $status ."'
    GROUP BY s.codigo
    ORDER BY id_stock ASC
```

resultado
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema aqui es el precio_in...Lo que necesito en resumen es traer exactamente los mismos valores, pero asociados al max(id_stock) para obtener el ultimo precio_in ingresado. Obviamente sin perder el resto de consultas como la suma

**Más información**
Si agrupo por codigo y a la vez por oc_id
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si hubiesen mas oc_id, aparecerían mas filas obviamente. Es el resultado de la última fila la que me sirve, pero no se como traerla sin perder la suma, ya que agrupando por oc_id se pierde (se divide). Solo agrupar por codigo

Esta misma pregunta la realicé en Stackoverflow en ingles, pero la respuesta no la pude adaptar a mi necesidad https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60765200/group-values-by-code-and-return-1-row-last-record-in-mysql?noredirect=1#comment107510392_60765200

Comment: Primer problema es que no veo las otras tablas, por ejemplo de donde sacas para hacer los valores `db1_servicios` por ejemplo, que contiene o por qué aparece `s.ubicacion` en tu tabla `db1_stock` y no lo colocaste en tu ejemplo. Muy poco puedo ayudar sin información, o mejor sería que resultado esperas.

Comment: Gracias @Synay por responder. No vi necesario la información de las otras tablas para ejemplificar, aunque quizás me equivoque. Esta tabla **db1_servicios** recoge un count por codigo y sirve para restar al **SUM(s.cantidad)** que viene de **db1_stock** y mostrar un total por codigo

Básicamente el resultado esperado es el mismo que tengo actualmente, pero que corresponda a la fila del **MAX(id_stock)**. Si te fijas, el **precio_in** para el mismo codigo tiene 3 valores distitnos, y siempre estoy recibiendo de vuelta el valor del mas antiguo